# How to load the URL in InAppbrowser within 20 secs?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am working in a cordova project and I am very new to cordova.

In that I have an requirement is like I am calling a url in the InAppbrowser . If the network connection is very slow(i.e. 20Kbps/ 50Kbps) I have to show an alert that ’Network slow’. Here I am using the  `setTimeout` function and also I am checking the internet connection. But my problem is if internet connection is there the setTimeout function also calling after 20 secs.

I want to check only if internet connection is slow or else once my `InAppbrowser` load with url my `setTimeout` function should not call. Could anypne please help to resolve this issue. My code is like this.....

```
  if(cid == null){
              curl = “some url”;

            //ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(curl, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');
                      ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(curl, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');
 setTimeout(function(){
    //alert("Hello");

  if( startEndedVar == true)
    {
  ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(curl, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');
       }
    else{
        ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("settings.html", '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');

          }
  }, 3000);

  ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {

                                           //alert('laoding started');

                                           });

      ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {

      startEndedVar = true;
      //alert('laoding ended');
  });
  ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event){
              screen.orientation.lock('portrait').then(function(obj) {
                console.log(obj);
            }, function(obj) {
                console.log(obj);
            });
            });

          }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you just use cordova-plugin-network-information and detect 2g connections?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the same order twice: `ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(curl, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');`. Thanks to the `if` and `else` your going to open a window in each mode, also your TimeOut is called aufer 30s and not after 20s.

I'm not sure if there are some deeper problems in the logic.